# Leute VS Man - which one is it?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If I wanna say that for example "people (in general) sleep at this hour", what will be the right choise?

> Leute schlafen um diese Zeit

Or

> Man schläft um diese Zeit

When is *man* the right choise and when *Leute*?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the definite article, it's *some people*, if you use it, it's a group of people in question.

> Leute schlafen um diese Zeit.

*Some people sleep at this hour.*

> Die Leute schlafen um diese Zeit.

*These people sleep at this hour.*

If you want to say *people in general* you have to write out this *in general* as *die meisten*.

> Die meisten Leute schlafen um diese Zeit.

*(Most) people sleep at this hour.*

If you use *man* instead and address someone, you make it a rather harsh admonishment:

> Man schläft um diese Zeit.

*One sleeps at this hour. (so you should, too)*